# Recursion in J language

Tags: recursion, j

I have an initial (10 x 2) vector v1, and a (100 x 10 x 10) matrix Cos. The dyad verb 'move' returns another (10 x 2) vector using (10 x 10) i th matrix from Cos as an input.

```
$Cos
   100 10 10
$v1 
   10 2 
v1
    0.89 0.91    
    0.01 0.24
    0.88 0.43
    0.43 0.32
    0.85 0.84
    0.27 0.31
    0.1  0.11
    0.49 0.9
    0.2  0.28
    0.66 0.96
(0{Cos) move v1
    1         1
    0.426426  0
    0.819478  0.304798
    0.66484   0.0362481
    0.505905  0.278294
    0.149514  0.0516271
    0         0.40583
    0.233825  0.759351
    0.03464   0.630262
    0.502968  0.686788
```

I want to make a matrix using a recursion such that

```
$p
   100 10 2
```

like

```
0{p =: (0{Cos) move (v1)
1{p =: (1{Cos) move (p0)
2{p =: (2{Cos) move (p1)
...
```

I am currently reading recursion section (1:`) from the J language wiki, but I am a little confused.

Should I just simply use loop using ^:?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe I would try

```
move~/\ v1, cos
```

this would insert `move` between successive items of a list formed by prepending v1 to cos. The `~` (Reflex adverb) would mean that your insertion of `move` would first get the result of `O{cos move v1` then `1{cos move (0{cos move v1)` which is the same as `1{cos move (0{p)` and by your definition above this would be the value of `1{p` and so on through the entire array.

Recursion is usually reserved for cases where problems can be broken down into simpler problems until an answer is returned up the chain. Since this does not seem like that type of a problem, this may be the reason that recursion is confusing you.

Comment: Hello, Bob.
I have tried this, but the problem is that '(1{cos)) move ((0{Cos) move v1 )' is not the same as '(2{Cos) move (p1)' while '(0{Cos) move v1' is exactly the same as '0{ move~/\ v1, cos'

Comment: That is, '(1{cos) move  (0{cos) move v1' was not equal to '2{move~/\ v1, cos' while '(0{cos) move v1' was equal to '1{move~/\ v1, cos'Do you have any idea why this is happening? Thank you for helping me = ]

Comment: I was thinking that `p0` is the same as `0{p` and `p1` is the same as `1{p` etc. If that is true then `p0` would be equal to `(0{Cos) move (v1)` If that is not true, then my solution would not work. Now that I look at it the way that you have written `0{p =: (0{Cos) move (v1)` would assign  `(0{Cos) move (v1) `to `p` and the `0{p` would return the first item of `p`, but would not change that assignment. Maybe if you could provide the code for `move`, it might help?

Comment: I tried your method with a simpler verb, and it worked perfectly on that simple one. I will try to solve this problem by myself first! Thank you, Bob. J always challenges me which makes it so fun to learn = ]